# How to convert Columnar data into rows

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have data in columns for each country and I am trying to convert into a row with name as country with all country names and their values in another field.

tried pivot, pivot_table but nothing is working as expected.

Comment: add sample data with desired output

Comment: Read [mcve] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: How do you expect us to help with no information on the problem at all ? ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
   columns=["Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3"],
   data=[[1,2,3]]
)
```

So this is your current output?

```
   Country 1  Country 2  Country 3
0          1          2          3
```

And you'd like to transpose it?

```
df.transpose()

           0
Country 1  1
Country 2  2
Country 3  3
```